# $all Operator in Casbah

Tags: casbah

Could you please give me an example of how to use the `$all` operator for my two `elemMatch` objects?

```
val elemMatch1 = foo()
val elemMatch2 = bar()
```

How can I perform the query of `$all( elemMatch1, elemMatch2)` (all documents where elemMatch1 and elemMatch2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much sense it makes to mix `$all` and `$elemMatch` but from the docs `$all` follows:

```
{ <field>: { $all: [ <value> , <value1> ... ] }
```

$elemMatch follows:

```
{ array: { $elemMatch: <document> } }
```

Unfortunately, the casbah DSL won't help there as `$all` requires a list and `$elemMatch` expects a string, so you have to manually have to build the document:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
val coll = MongoClient()("test")("testB")

coll += MongoDBObject("array" -> List(
            MongoDBObject("value1" -> 1, "value2" -> 0),
            MongoDBObject("value1" -> 1, "value2" -> 2)
        ))

val elemMatch = MongoDBObject("$elemMatch" -> MongoDBObject("value1" -> 1, "value2" -> 2))
val query = "array" $all List(elemMatch)

coll.find(query).count
```